# Running facial recognition script in Django

Tags: python, django, facial-identification

I have a facial recognition script in my django app, below is the code, It returns a string which is the name of the person found. The script works well on its own  when i pass an image parameter to it. I want to run this script in my views.py so when i get a name, i search for the name in my models then get a matching result. The templates loads just fine but after uploading the image and i submit no action take place.

```
def identify_face(imagename):
    known_face_encodings = []
    known_face_names = []
    known_faces_filenames = []

    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('assets/img/users/'):
        known_faces_filenames.extend(filenames)
        break

    for filename in known_faces_filenames:
        face = face_recognition.load_image_file('assets/img/users/' + filename)
        known_face_names.append(re.sub("[0-9]",'', filename[:-4]))
        known_face_encodings.append(face_recognition.face_encodings(face)[0])


    face_locations = []
    face_encodings = []
    face_names = []
    imagename_new =  face_recognition.load_image_file(imagename)
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(imagename_new)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(imagename_new, face_locations)

    face_names = []

    for face_encoding in face_encodings:
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        name = "Unknown"

        face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

        face_names.append(name)

    return name
```

This is my forms.py and views.py code

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
from .models import MyData
from cisdb.forms import SearchForm,ImageUploadForm
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
from cisdb.face_recogniton_script import identify_citizen


def citizen_match(request):
    form = ImageUploadForm()
    query = None
    match = ''
    results = []
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['query']
            match = identify_citizen(query)
            results = MyData.objects.annotate(
                        search=SearchVector('first_name', 'last_name','other_name'),
                        ).filter(search=match)
    return render(request,'match.html',{'form': form,'query': query, 'results': results,'match':match})
```

match.html

```
{% block content %}
  {% if query %}
    <h3>
      {% with results.count as total_results %}
          Found {{ total_results }} result{{ total_results|pluralize }}
      {% endwith %}
    </h3>
    {% for data in results %}
        <div class="section">
        <div class="container"></div>
          <h4><a href="{{ data.get_absolute_url }}">{{ data.last_name }}  {{data.first_name}} {{ data.other_name }}</a></h4>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
      <p>No matches found.</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><a href="{% url "match" %}">Match again</a></p>
  {% else %}
    <h1>Match faces</h1>
    <form action="." method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Match">
    </form>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This i all i get from the command the command line

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 05, 2020 - 13:14:21
Django version 2.2, using settings 'CIS.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Feb/2020 13:14:29] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[05/Feb/2020 13:14:32] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4078
[05/Feb/2020 13:14:32] "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 200 412
[05/Feb/2020 13:14:32] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 17944
[05/Feb/2020 13:14:32] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16378
[05/Feb/2020 13:14:40] "GET /match_data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1597
[05/Feb/2020 13:14:40] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Feb/2020 13:14:51] "GET /match_data/?image=warren2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 1597
```

Comment: it seems you sends only filename but not real image - you should rather use `POST`, not `GET` to send it.

Comment: Understood i will try it out now